# Is there a way to multiply elements in list of pairs

Tags: ocaml

Hello I'm trying to write a program in OCaml and was wondering if there is a way to get from list of pairs : [(1,2);(2,3);(3;5)] to a list where pairs are multiplied [2;6;15] this is what i have tried but it's giving me Exception: Failure "hd"

```
let rec mul l=
    let x=(List.hd l) and y=(List.tl l) in
    ((fst x)*(snd x))::(mul y);;
mul [(3, 5); (3, 4); (3, 3);];;
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation for `List.hd` to see in which cases it might throw a `Failure` exception?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I think there must be simpler methods. Specifically, you have a list of `n` elements which are pairs (so a list of type `(int * int) list`) and you want to get a list of the same size, but which is the result of multiplying the two members of the pair. So, going from an `(int * int) list` to an `int list`.

As the objective is to preserve the size of the list, you can rephrase the statement by saying "I would like to apply a function on each element of my list". It is possible to do this manually, using, for example, pattern matching (which makes it possible to be explicit about the treatment of the empty list):

```ml
let rec mult my_list = 
   match my_list with 
   | [] -> (* case if my list is empty *)
      [] (* The process is done! *)
   | (a, b) :: tail -> (* if I have, at least, one element *)
      (a * b) :: (mult tail)
```

But generally, applying a function to each element of a list and preserving its size is called "mapping" (roughly), and fortunately there is a function in the standard OCaml library which allows this, and it is called, logically: `List.map`, here is its type: `val map : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list` which could be translated as: give me a function which goes from `'a` to `'b`, a list of `'a` and I can produce a list of `'b` for you.

Here, we would like to be able to apply a function that goes from `(int * int) -> int`, for example: `let prod (x, y) = x * y`. So let's try to reimplement `mult` in terms of `map`:

```ml
let mult my_list = 
   let prod (x, y) = x * y in
   List.map prod my_list
```

And voila, the pattern captured in the first purpose is exactly the idea behind `List.map`, for each element of a list, I apply a function and I keep the result of the function application.

Answer (score 1):

What you want essentially is `List.map (uncurry ( * ))`.

```
# let uncurry f (a, b) = f a b;;
val uncurry : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a * 'b -> 'c = <fun>
# List.map (uncurry ( * )) [(3, 5); (3, 4); (3, 3);];;
- : int list = [15; 12; 9]
```

(`uncurry` is a basic FP function, but unfortunately it isn't defined in OCaml's fairly sparse standard library. But as you can see the definition is straightforward.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution with the least amount of modification to your original code:

```
let rec mul l = 
  match l with
  | [] -> []      (* <-- Deal with the base case *)
  | _ ->          (* Same as before --> *)
    let x = List.hd l 
    and y = List.tl l
    in
    (fst x * snd x) :: mul y;;
```

Note that we just need to consider that happens when the list is empty, and we do that by matching on the list. The recursive case stays the same.

Comment: Simplified greatly by using pattern-matching rather than `List.hd`, `List.tl`, `fst`, and `snd`. `(a, b)::y -> (a * b) :: mul y`